# How to create a dictionary with a slash as key in postscript

Tags: dictionary, key, postscript, slash

So I know these basic dict commands in Postscript:

`i dict` creates a dictionary with `i` entries

`d begin` moves dictionary `d` to the dictionary stack

`end`      removes the topmost dictionary from the dictionary stack

`d n w put` store value `w` under name `n` in dictionary `d`

`d n get` get the value of name `n` in dictionary `d`, and put it on the stack

What I would like to do is create a dictionary that represents the associativity of differend operands. The `+` operand and the `-` operand share the same priority, therefor they are both set to 0, the `*` and `/` operands also share the same priority, but have higher priority than `+` and `-` and are therefor set to 1 and so on...

The Problem is, that I am not able to set the dictionary key to `/` as it is treated as some kind of "delimiter". Is there any way around this, since i cannot change the keys, and I cannot create a dict like this:

```
/prioritydict 5 dict def
prioritydict /(-) 0 put
prioritydict /(+) 0 put
prioritydict /(*) 1 put
prioritydict /(/) 1 put
prioritydict /(^) 2 put
```

nor like this:

```
/prioritydict 5 dict def
prioritydict /- 0 put
prioritydict /+ 0 put
prioritydict /* 1 put
prioritydict // 1 put
prioritydict /^ 2 put
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: From the PSLRM3: A / (slash—not backslash) introduces a literal name. The slash is not part of the name itself, but is a preﬁx indicating that the following sequence of zero or more regular characters constitutes a literal name object. There can be no white-space characters between the / and the name. The characters // (two slashes) introduce an immediately evaluated name. Note: The token / (a slash followed by no regular characters) is a valid literal name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **cvn** (convert to name) operator to turn a string of any form you want into a literal name.  These should all be equivalent:

```
prioritydict <2f> cvn 1 put

prioritydict (\/) cvn 1 put

prioritydict (\057) cvn 1 put
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your middle example. `/` is not special in strings so there's no need to escape it. It may be implementation-dependent whether `(\/) cvn` compares equal to `(/) cvn`.

Comment: cvn is exactly what I was looking for! (/)works fine for me and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for this :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
%!

/prioritydict 5 dict def

prioritydict begin

/+ 0 def
/- 0 def
/* 1 def
%// 1 def    conflicts with immediately evaluated name
/^ 2 def

* ^ add =
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to mention it using a literal name, then you can use just a single slant.

```
/
```

That is, an empty name indicated by just the decorator followed by zero characters before the next delimiter (space or newline or parens or braces).

You should be able to define it and load it, but you can't directly make an executable name for it, so you can't make use of automatic loading like with other definitions.

```
/ 1 def
/ load =
/ cvx exec =
```